# Docker container recovery from dead filesystem

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-container, docker-volume, data-recovery

I have a filesystem image after a docker host crash.
There was a docker mongodb container running the moment it crashed.
How could I get the container along with its volume back up and running in order to do a mongodbdump ?